# How to build project with AspectJ using Ant

Tags: ant, aspectj

Our project is using AspectJ. It works fine in Eclipse IDE since it's AspectJ project in Eclipse IDE (having AspectJ Runtime in classpath)
But it doesnt work if we use ant to build the project in UNIX. I have seen some articles mention ivy target, I'm looking for more details on how to config my AspectJ project to build it with Ant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some googling, I found that I need to create the aop.xml under META-INF and add the aspectjweaver.jar to the jvm options in ant build.properties. The aspect seems working since I saw the methods being intercepted. But I found below exception at startup:

`ERROR org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.BcelWorld - Unable to find class 'Object' in repository
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Object not found - unable to determine URL
        at org.aspectj.apache.bcel.util.ClassLoaderRepository.loadClass(ClassLoaderRepository.java:292) ~[aspectjweaver.jar.0:1.7.3]
        at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.BcelWorld.lookupJavaClass(BcelWorld.java:402) [aspectjweaver.jar.0:1.7.3]
        at org.aspectj.weaver.bcel.BcelWorld.resolveDelegate(BcelWorld.java:376) [aspectjweaver.jar.0:1.7.3]
...`

My @Aspect class looks like this:

```
@Aspect
public class CaseInsensitiveEqualsAspect {

    @Pointcut("call(boolean equals(Object)) && args(compareString) && target(sourceString) && within(com.sample.package..*)")
    public void equalsPointcut(final Object compareString, final String sourceString) {}


    @Around("equalsPointcut(compareString, sourceString)")
    public Object around(final ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint, final Object compareString, final String sourceString)
            throws Throwable {
        System.out.println(">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>Invoking equalsIgnoreCase...");
        return sourceString.equalsIgnoreCase(compareString != null ? compareString.toString() : null);
    }
}
```